# What is the Errors endpoint used for?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to figure out what the `errors` endpoint is used for, so I can I can implement it in my API.

I have been trying things like:

- http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/errors/404
- http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/errors/0
- http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/errors/1
- http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/errors/500

And I am getting a File Not Found Error in Firefox.

All the errors help page says is:

> **Summary**
>   Simulates an error given a code

What are valid error codes?  And, can we get some sort of response telling us that we supplied a bad error code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/errors` method was requested to make it easier to test libraries.  Finding questions/users/etc. that result in certain error cases can be... trying, and potentially quite brittle.

Defined Error Codes:

- [NotFound](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/404) = 404
- [InternalServerError](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/500) = 500
- [InvalidApplicationPublicKey](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/4000) = 4000
- [InvalidPageSize](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/4001) = 4001
- [InvalidSort](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/4002) = 4002
- [InvalidOrder](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/4003) = 4003
- [RequestLimitExceeded](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/4004) = 4004
- [InvalidVectorFormat](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/4005) = 4005
- [TooManyIds](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/4006) = 4006
- [UnconstrainedSearch](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/4007) = 4007
- [InvalidTags](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/4008) = 4008
- [Offline](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/9999) = 9999

Invalid error codes result in a 404 error (NotFound).

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example link for a working error call to the api?

Comment: http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/4005

Answer (score 2):

Pass the parameter `?type=jsontext` to see error JSON

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/errors/404?type=jsontext

http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/errors/500?type=jsontext

<s>**Note**: if you don't put `?type=jsontext`, error code is simulated only in http response header, so firefox just give you error page.</s>

Comment: This is incorrect, the JSON body is always returned.  Firefox just doesn't show it to you by default.  Either view source, or watch the HTTP traffic in a sniffer to see the error message.

Comment: @Kevin, You're right, I've crossed-out that part, my firefox just gave me alert `Firefox can't find the file at http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/errors/4005.`, view-source was not viewable, so I assumed it was only in http headers. didn't watch with HTTP traffic, I stand corrected.