# Getting Question data using stack.PHP fails after a certain number of requests

Tags: support, api, documentation, rate-limit, limits

I am trying to build an RSS feed that includes any/all questions that I have answered, and been accepted as the correct answer.

I am running into an issue where I'm sending too many requests and wonder if there is a more simple way to accomplish it.  (I am using stackphp)

***Steps I am taking***

1. Get My profile (for total answer count)
2. Get All my answers
3. Loop through All answers (using total count/pagesize to iterate through multiple pages if need be. And filter answers (checking if accepted)
4. Build a Questions array by Grabbing each question associated with each answer (`$answer['question_id']`) individually

Then I (theoretically) will have an answers array and a questions array with corresponding keys that will hold only accepted answers/questions

It gets through a certain number of requests and then fails, I believe I'm overloading the API (I'm using an API key).

Is there any way to (through the API) ask to have the question body/title included with answers?  And/or is there a better way to approach this that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: I'm the author of stack.PHP.*

You're likely running into [rate limit](https://stackapps.com/questions/1143/request-throttling-limits) issues. The API only allows you to make som many requests per second. Quoting from the question I linked to:

> The API will cut you off if you make more than 30 requests over 5 seconds to any single endpoint.

Based on past experience, what you need to do is make sure that there is a 100ms delay between requests (I know, that's nowhere near 30/s but there have been issues with that in the past).

Comment: that was it! thanks, btw you might look in your `UserExchange` file, I think you are re-defaulting the ttl to 10 in the `UserExchange` constructor.  Had to fix that to get it to work

Comment: @jon: Yes, thank you - I have already fixed it in the repository but that fix hasn't made it to the downloadable archives yet :)