# Throttling Question

Tags: support, api

Hey all,

I keep getting kicked out of the API.

Is throttling set to 30 requests per 5 seconds?

j

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific limits are also given in [this faq entry](https://stackapps.com/questions/1143/request-throttling-limits).