# Error Code when API Key Limit exceeds

Tags: discussion, documentation

What will the error code be generated when API Key Limit exceeds? I need that because I have to handle this error in my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Kevin's answer here: [What is the Errors endpoint used for?](https://stackapps.com/questions/408/what-is-the-errors-endpoint-used-for/411#411)

> [RequestLimitExceeded](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/errors/4004) = 4004