# How many ids is 'too many'?

Tags: support, api, documentation

[This answer](https://stackapps.com/questions/408/what-is-the-errors-endpoint-used-for) mentions limit on amount of ids included in queries like `/users/{id}/mentioned`, but I can't find actual amount mentioned anywhere.

Now, I could run binary search and find out, but I thought I'd ask first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/619/url-length-limit-for-for-requests-taking-vectorised-ids-answers-id-question/620#620) answer, it looks like 100.